# Java: ways to start a thread

Tags: multithreading

I have found the basics for building a simple Java chat at the following [link](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html):

Basically, the ChatClient starts a ChatClientThread with the following code:

```
if (thread == null)
  {  client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
     thread = new Thread(this);                   
     thread.start();
  }
```

can someone help me to understand the difference between the above code and this:

```
 if (thread == null)
{  client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);                   
 client.start();
}
```

Is it made only to set thread != null or there is a specific reason? And how is the "client" thread passed to the new Thread wit the word "this" in this case?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: The first version, you start a thread that is going to call run on 'this', whatever 'this' is. The second version, you start the ChatClientThread. Which will cause its run method to be called.

Comment: As answered by @matt , the difference is actually how you want to control it. The second example , does not look so accurate tho , because if `client.start();` invokes a new thread , then the `thread == null` check ,  doesn't  actually control that thread reference , thats still an assumption , because you havent posted which one is holding the `thread` reference.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

The short answer is that the one with thread.start() creates 2 threads, the one with client.start() creates 1 thread with a likely `IllegalThreadStateException` being thrown.

To fully explain the scenario I will break down the problem into 3 parts; the thread.start() code, the client.start() code, and the ChatClientThread instantiation.

---

**Part 1 -- thread.start()**

```
if (thread == null)
{  
    client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
    thread = new Thread(this);                   
    thread.start();
}
```

In this code block occurs the following steps:

1. Check if the `thread` is `null`
2. Instantiate the `client` variable as a new instance of `ChatClientThread` with *this* current `ChatClient` as its client and `socket` as its socket.
3. Instantiate the thread with its runnable as *this* current object instance. When an object implements the interface `Runnable`, the object must override `public void run()`. The `Thread` class implementation will execute the provided Runnable's `run()` method.
4. Start the thread. This will execute the `ChatClient`'s respective `run()` method because we instantiated the thread with it as it's `runnable`.

Below is the to-be executed by `thread.start()`:

```
public void run() 
{  
    while (true) 
    {  
        try 
        {  
            streamOut.writeUTF(console.readLine());
            streamOut.flush();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("Sending error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            stop();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Part 2 -- client.start()**

```
if (thread == null)
{  
    client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);                   
    client.start();
}
```

In this code block occurs the following steps:

1. Check if the `thread` is `null`
2. Instantiate the `client` variable as a new instance of `ChatClientThread` with *this* current `ChatClient` as its client and `socket` as its socket.
3. Start the `ChatClientThread`. This will execute the `ChatClientThread`'s `run()` method.

Below is the code to be executed by `client.start()`:

```
public void run() 
{  
    while (true) 
    {  
        try 
        {  
            client.handle(streamIn.readUTF());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) 
        {
            System.out.println("Listening error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            client.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Part 3 -- ChatClientThread Instantiation**

Now, the ChatClientThread constructor contains some important code to note.

```
public ChatClientThread(ChatClient _client, Socket _socket)
{  
    client   = _client;
    socket   = _socket;
    open();  
    start();
}
```

In this code block occurs the following steps:

1. Initialize the `client` variable
2. Initialize the `socket` variable
3. Execute the `open()` function. This function creates the DataInputSteam object that will be used for receiving input.
4. Execute the `start()` function. This function will start *this* instance of `ChatClientThread` and execute it's respective `run()` method. Note, that the current state of the `ChatClientThread` at this point is running. If we relook at **Part 2**'s code, we will see that after the initialization of the `client` variable `client.start()` is executed. This will likely throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` due to the thread being started twice. Once started, start cannot be called again on a thread.

Below is the to-be executed by `start()`:

```
public void run() {  
    while (true)
    {  
        try
        {  
            client.handle(streamIn.readUTF());
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {  
            System.out.println("Listening error: " + ioe.getMessage());
            client.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Conclusion**

In **Part 1**, the application will create 2 threads; one is the `ChatClientThread` running it's own `run()` method, and the other is the `thread` variable running the `ChatClient`'s `run()` method.

In **Part 2**, the application will create 1 thread; the `ChatClientThread` running it's own `run()` method. The `client.start()` function will likely throw an `IllegalThreadStateException` because the `ChatClientThread` will have been started twice.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(thread == null)
{
  client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
  thread = new Thread(this);
  thread.start();
}

if(thread == null)
{
  client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
  client.start();
}

Here you need to aware about the following things

first "this" => this is keyword in java which returns running instance of class
second "ChatClientThread" => ChatClientThread declared as follows

"public class ChatClientThread extends Thread " that means ChatClientThread is child class of Thread class.

So in first block we are passing Runnable object(this) to the ChatClientThread which will then pass to thread,=> client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
and in next statement we are passing Runnable object(this) to the thread itself.=>
 thread = new Thread(this);
So in first block we are having two runnable instance that can be run
and in second we have only one ie. customized ChatClientThread
```